# Chronometer start from specific value in Notification RemoteViews

Tags: android, android-notifications, chronometer, android-remoteview

I'm trying to start the chronometer in a new notification but from a paused(elapsed) "the elapsed time is got from another chronometer", not from zero

The start `base` in Notification `RemoteViews.class` of chronometer is different from the start base in `Chronometer.class` it has different calculations

```
Notification notification = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(songName).build();
notification.contentView = simpleContentView;
```

And I get the `timeWhenPaused`

```
long timeWhenPaused = myChronometer.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

Then create the `chronometer`

```
notification.contentView.setChronometer(R.id.chronometer_recorder
                            , (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeWhenPaused)
                            , null
                            , true
                    );
```

It starts from Zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many method with calculations finally got this.

```
long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - myChronometer.getBase();
```

Then

```
notification.contentView.setChronometer(R.id.chronometer_recorder_notification
                    ,(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - elapsedMillis ^5)
                    ,null
                    ,true
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help >>>>
my working example of a chronometer using remote views (in the notification).

```
long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();  // time in future
         endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, YOUR_HOUR);
         endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, YOUR_MINUTE);
         endTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Date now = new Date();
long elapsed = now.getTime() - endTime.getTimeInMillis();
long remainingTime = startTime - elapsed;

        remoteViews.setChronometerCountDown(R.id.chronometer, true);
        remoteViews.setChronometer(R.id.chronometer, remainingTime, ("%tH:%tM:%tS"), true);
```

[picture of my notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj1mX.jpg)